# Call text to speech from class separate to activity class

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to create a class which can be called from any activity to speak the text from an EditText box. When I run the code I currently have, it plays the alert sound but then fails to play the Text to Speech content. What do I need to change to get the text to play too? I know the activity layout XML code is correct because the Text To Speech code works when it is directly in the activity class. I have looked around for a solution but nowhere else outlines how to do this from a thread context.

I have included my code below:

**on AircraftMain.java**

```
View.OnClickListener speakBtnOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String toSpeak = textToSpeak.getText().toString();
            TextToSpeak speak = new TextToSpeak(AircraftMain.this, toSpeak);
            speak.run();

        }
    };
```

**TextToSpeak.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TextToSpeak implements Runnable {

    private Activity activity;
    private static String text;
    private static TextToSpeech talk;

    public TextToSpeak(Activity activity, String toSpeak) {
        this.activity = activity;
        text = toSpeak;
    }

    public void run() {

        talk = new TextToSpeech(activity, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    talk.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }
        });

        talk.addEarcon("Attention", "com.kieronmc.aircraftgps", R.raw.warning_beep);
        talk.playEarcon("Attention", QUEUE_ADD,null);    
        talk.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
        talk.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I not implementing it on the last code line? `talk.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);`

Comment: I think the mediaPlayer you created is preventing the speak method from doing what is supposed to do. Instead of using  mediaPlayer to start an alert sound, you can use AddEarcon and PlayEarcon methonds provided here [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html).

Comment: Are you sure onInit() has been called before you try talk.speak?

Comment: I have changed the code to use AddEarcon and PlayEarcon and now there is no sound playing. Seems like there is an issue with sound coming out. Possibly the onInit() method isn't being called. How would I change the code to ensure onInit() is being called?

Comment: The errors i'm getting are about not being bound to TTS engine. e.g. `W/TextToSpeech: playEarcon failed: not bound to TTS engine;
W/TextToSpeech: setLanguage failed: not bound to TTS engine;
W/TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine;`

Comment: Your implementation is flawed, but move everything inside `status != TextToSpeech.ERROR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code, It should work:

1) Create a text to speech Initializer as follows:

```
public class TextToSpeechInitializer{

private Context context;
private static TextToSpeech talk;
private TextToSpeechIniListener callback;
private Locale locale;

public TextToSpeechInitializer(Context context , Locale locale , TextToSpeechIniListener l) {
    this.context = context;
    if(l != null) {
        callback = l;
    }
    this.locale = locale;
    initialize();
}


private void initialize() {
    talk = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                talk.setLanguage(locale); //TODO: Check if locale is available before setting.
                callback.onSucces(talk);
            }else{
                callback.onFailure(talk);
                Log.e("TTS","TextToSpeechInitializeError");
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

2) The above initializer class calls this interface class to notify the activity below (TTS Success or Failure) :

```
public interface TextToSpeechIniListener {

public void onSucces(TextToSpeech tts);

public void onFailure(TextToSpeech tts);
}
```

3) Activity

```
public class Demo7 extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeechIniListener {

private Button b;
private TextToSpeechInitializer i;
private TextToSpeech talk;
private boolean flag = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo7);
    i = new TextToSpeechInitializer(this, Locale.UK, this);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);


    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(flag) {
                talk.addEarcon("Attention", getPackageName(), R.raw.androidcalm);
                talk.playEarcon("Attention", QUEUE_ADD, null);
                //talk.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                talk.speak("Hello, Testing", QUEUE_ADD, null);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(talk != null){
        talk.stop();
        talk.shutdown();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSucces(TextToSpeech tts) {
    this.talk = tts;
    flag = true;
}

@Override
public void onFailure(TextToSpeech tts) {
    flag = false;
    finish();
}
}
```

layout demo7.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:text="speak"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Don't forget to change R.raw.androidcalm to your raw resource file.

Comment: You should not be using an Activity context. It will create a potential leak